# What is "errno 34" when booting Mac OSX 10.6?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, kernel-panic

My mother's Mac Pro running Snow Leopard recently crashed on startup. I'm trying to help her fix it but have no idea where to start. She gets the following error screen:

[image]

Text:

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0x47f5ad): "Process 1 exec of /sbin/launchd failed, errno 34\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/bsd/kern/kern_exec.c:3145
Debugger called: <panic>
...snip backtrace...

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: init

Mac OS version:
not yet set

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun 7 16:33:36 MDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3-1/RELEASE_1386
System modelname: MacPro1,1 (Mac-F4208DCA)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1066084224
```

What is wrong with the computer and how can I fix it?

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: Kernel 10.8.0 is Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

Comment: thanks. I wasn't sure, im trying to keep her calm remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errno 34 is "ERANGE" Result too large.

That doesn't help too much. Some googling on kernel panics that early suggest you should try booting from install discs and do a disk repair.  A confused filesystem can cause a kernel panic (though it's unlikely).

There's an [Apple Support Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742)  that suggests fixes.  It boils down to

1. Try Safe Boot by holding Shift down while booting.
2. Boot from install media and try a disk repair
3. Install to an external drive and try running from there to see if it's a drive problem or other hardware.
4. Disconnect hardware to try to isolate it.
5. Reseat ram and other connections.
6. Reinstall OS X on the internal media doing an Archive and Install to see if it's a OS install issue.